# How can I build with ant as a normal user (no need for sudo) COOJA

Tags: ant, iot, sudoers, cooja, contiki-ng

Recently I started working on a project in IoT, using contiki-ng.
The problem I faced is when I tried to run cooja with:

```
$ ant run
```

under `~/contiki-ng/tools/cooja`.
the build failed

```
$ ant run
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
Buildfile: /home/user/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/build.xml

init:

compile:

copy configs:

jar_cooja:
     [jar] Building jar: /home/user/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/dist/cooja.jar

jar:

init:

compile:

jar:

init:

mspsim:

init:

compile:

jar:

coffee:

init:

compile:
   [javac] Compiling 8 source files to /home/user/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/tools/coffee-manager/build
   [javac] Note: /home/user/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/tools/coffee-manager/org/contikios/coffee/CoffeeConfiguration.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
   [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

configs:

jar:
     [jar] Building jar: /home/user/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/tools/coffee-manager/coffee.jar
    [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/user/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/apps/mspsim/lib

compile:

copy:

jar:

init:

compile:

jar:

init:

clean:
  [delete] Deleting directory /home/user/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/apps/serial_socket/build

BUILD FAILED
/home/user/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/build.xml:200: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/user/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/apps/serial_socket/build.xml:23: Unable to delete file /home/user/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/apps/serial_socket/build/org/contikios/cooja/serialsocket/SerialSocketClient$5.class

Total time: 2 seconds
```

I tried using `$ sudo ant run` , and it started working as it should, **without a problem**.
.
.
`$ ant run -verbose 2>> log;cat log` gives:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true

BUILD FAILED
/home/user/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/build.xml:200: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/user/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/apps/serial_socket/build.xml:23: Unable to delete file /home/user/contiki-ng/tools/cooja/apps/serial_socket/build/org/contikios/cooja/serialsocket/SerialSocketClient$5.class
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Delete.handle(Delete.java:775)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Delete.removeDir(Delete.java:822)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Delete.removeDir(Delete.java:818)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Delete.removeDir(Delete.java:818)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Delete.removeDir(Delete.java:818)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Delete.removeDir(Delete.java:818)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Delete.execute(Delete.java:641)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:299)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1401)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:36)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1264)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:437)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:299)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1401)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1374)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1264)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:818)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)

Total time: 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, first by checking the `build.xml`, the section where `run` is defined :

```
105.  <target name="run" depends="init, compile, jar, copy configs">
106.    <java fork="yes" dir="${build}" classname="org.contikios.cooja.Cooja" maxmemory="512m">
107.      <sysproperty key="user.language" value="en"/>
108.      <arg line="${args}"/>
109.      <env key="LD_LIBRARY_PATH" value="."/>
110.      <classpath>
111.        <pathelement path="${build}"/>
112.        <pathelement location="lib/jdom.jar"/>
113.        <pathelement location="lib/log4j.jar"/>
114.        <pathelement location="lib/syntaxpane-1.2.0.jar"/>
115.        <pathelement location="lib/swingx-all-1.6.4.jar"/>
116.      </classpath>
117.    </java>
118.  </target>
```

and you can see that its depends on `jar`.

```
 18.   Build COOJA (dist/cooja.jar) and all default projects (MSPSim et al)
 19.   > ant jar
```

so checking the `jar` section :

```
196.  <target name="jar" depends="jar_cooja">
197.    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="apps/mrm" target="jar" inheritAll="false"/>
198.    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="apps/mspsim" target="jar" inheritAll="false"/>
199.    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="apps/avrora" target="jar" inheritAll="false"/>
200.    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="apps/serial_socket" target="jar" inheritAll="false"/>
201.    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="apps/powertracker" target="jar" inheritAll="false"/>
202.  </target>
```

I can see that it try to manipulate the `./apps/serail_socket` but it failed.
so I checked then the owner and the right permission of those directories:

```
$ ls -li | awk '{print $1, $3, $4, $NF}'
total   
drwxr-xr-x root root build
-rw-r--r-- user user build.xml
-rw-r--r-- root root cooja.config
drwxr-xr-x root root java
drwxr-xr-x root root lib
-rw-r--r-- root root serial-socket.jar
```

The owner was `root` and not the normal user. maybe I ran the :
`git submodule update --init --recursive` command by mistake with `sudo` or something.
so I changed the owner of those files and directories :
`sudo chown -h -R user ./apps/serail_socket ./apps/powertracker`

And then its **worked as it should**.